# What am I doing wrong with arrays

Tags: c#

I am trying to pass a string array from one form to another form in c#
I have tried this code from form 1:

```
 Form f2 = new Form2(Val);

 f2.Show();
```

Here is the code from the second form:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string[] _vals;
    public Form2(string[] vals) 
    {
        _vals = vals;
        Form Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String BoxText="";
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            BoxText = BoxText + _vals[i];
        }

        MessageBox.Show(BoxText);
    }
}
```

The last part of the code is just checking to see if values are actually being passed.  But it says I need some sort of object reference to the instance.
What am I doing wrong if all I want is to pass the string array to the next form.

Comment: Why are you creating *another* `Form2` instance in the `Form2` constructor?

Comment: What is this? Why do You call your default ctor from Your second

Comment: Also, you might be going out of the array bounds in your `for` loop.  You have hard coded 9 values into the loop, so if `_vals` has less than 9 values, you will throw an exception.  I would generally do `for (int i = 0; i < _vals.Length; i++)` instead.

Comment: I think the down-votes are unnecessary as he's clearly new to C# and needs help understanding it. Everyone needs to learn somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

this should help in your custom ctor:

```
public Form2(string[] vals) 
{
     InitializeComponent();
     _vals = vals;
}
```

What you where experiencing(mainly) was the lack of the form initialization(initializecomponent),and then you called form2 with the default ctor which did not have the array initialized.

Comment: This doesn't explain anything about what you changed, why it was important, or how it was causing the problem(s) that he was seeing.  Just a code dump alone is simply insufficient for a question like this.

Comment: @Servy,your right,i hope my little(very little) explanation did a bit right thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of these lines:

```
Form Form2 = new Form2();
Form2.Show();
```

in the constructor. When you execute those two lines in `Form1` you are loading an instance of `Form2`, but you don't want to create and load *another* instance of `Form2` when constructing `Form2`.

To clarify, the issue is that the **second instance** of `Form2` that's being created is throwing the exception because in the constructor of the **first instance** you're building a **second instance** with the *default* constructor.

And as stated in the comments, the reason the text box is empty is because you're not actually assigning `BoxText`, the `string`, to the `Text` property of a text box on the form.

And as stated in many other answers, you'll need to call `InitializeComponent();` as the very first line in the second constructor.

Comment: While those probably are wrong, it doesn't seem to be causing his current problem.

Comment: @Servy It very well might be his current problem.  His exception might be getting trown from the second form

Comment: @Servy, on load of the **second instance** of `Form2` the `_vals` would be `null` because of the default constructor. This is causing the error to be thrown.

Comment: Ok, when I tried adding the string array to the richtextbox it shows a blank form.  the textbox doesn't show up at all.  It made me thing that maybe it wasn't loading to the load event

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud That should really be in the answer, as that's kinda a key point.

Answer (score 1):

You have two contructor for Form2

1)

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

2)

```
public Form2(string[] vals) 
{
    _vals = vals;
    Form Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.Show();

}
```

First you are calling contructor with `string[]` parameter `New Form2(Vals)` after that inside your second constructor you again created `Form2` new instance and called `Show()` method so, On `Show()` method call, `Form2_Load` event handler is called and `_vals` is `NULL` at that time that's why it's thorwing an error object reference not set to and instance of object.

I suggest you to remove new Form2 object creation from second contructor and define your contructor like this and remove first constructor,

```
public Form2(string[] vals) 
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _vals = vals;

}
```

**Final Code should like this**

```
Form f2 = new Form2(Val);
f2.Show();


public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private string[] _vals;
    public Form2(string[] vals) 
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vals = vals;

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String BoxText="";
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            BoxText = BoxText + _vals[i];
        }

        MessageBox.Show(BoxText);
    }
}
```

**OR you can do like this,**

```
Form f2 = new Form2(Val);
f2.Show();


public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string[] _vals;
    public Form2(string[] vals): this() 
    {

        _vals = vals;

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String BoxText="";
        for (int i = 1; i < 11; ++i)
        {
            BoxText = BoxText + _vals[i];
        }

        MessageBox.Show(BoxText);
    }
}
```

Here `: this()`

This syntax allows you to call one constructor from another within the same class. So, `Form2()` without parameter contructor will call first and after that `Form2(string[] vals)` contructor will call.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Form2(string[] vals) 
    {
        _vals = vals;
        Form Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();

    }
```

you are trying to show form from its constructor only, you should not do that
instead you can initialize

```
public Form2(string[] vals) 
{
     InitializeComponent();
    _vals = vals;
}
```

Comment: Although you might have demonstrated that you understand where the problem lies, It's the OP who has to understand the answer.  you should explain it more